# Why does 0000 starts with 0x303030?

Tags: c

So, I am trying to understand this code.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void test(const char* p){
    int* ip = (int*)p;

    printf("%lu\n", sizeof(ip));
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(ip); ++i)
    {
        printf("%d\n", ip[i]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    test( argv[1] );
    return 0;
}
```

But when I input something it always has 8 rows.

When I input 0, the ouput is:

```
1213399088
1028410437
1852400175
1935761967
1163133032
1313426770
1398756181
1229734485
```

When I input 00:

```
1392521264
1280066888
1768042301
1633824622
1409312883
1229804101
1599296846
1279415635
```

000:

```
3158064
1279608915
1647263052
1647275625
6845281
1297237332
1398099529
1112888159
```

And when I input 0000 and so on, the first row is always `808464432` that has hex `0x30303030`:

```
808464432
1162367744
792546380
795765090
1752392034
1380275200
1431193933
1431527251
```

When I input 0 for 8 times, the first two rows start with 808464432:

```
808464432
808464432
1162367744
792546380
795765090
1752392034
1380275200
1431193933
```

And when I input 0 for 32 times, all of the rows become `808464432`.

So what I am curious is, why does it always have 8 rows? What are these number? Why 0x303030?

I want to know what's happening, but I don't know where to start looking. Thank you.

Comment: The reason you're getting 8 rows is that the size of an `int *` (pointer to integer) is 8, and you're access random garbage as you walk the pointer that is not really an array.

Comment: `sizeof(ip)` does not work like you think it does. It's going to return the size of the pointer itself - a fixed value.

Comment: Did you write the code in the first place? What are you hoping for it to accomplish?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel no, I did not. the complete version is on pwnable.kr(collision). But I want to understand what the code means. So, I took some of the parts for "experiment"

Comment: @SteveFriedl so, the numbers actually have no meaning, since it is accessed from something that is not even an array?

Comment: They are basically random pointer values; this program produces no meaningful output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is a big Undefined Behaviour as you read outside the `argv[1]` array bounds. you need to enter at least as many chars as you want to print. If sizeof(*int) is 8 and sizeof(int) is 4 you need to enter at least 32 chars.

Decimal numbers are not good to see that is going on on the byte level. It is better to use hex numbers.

```
void test(const void* p){
    const unsigned int* ip = p;
    const unsigned char *ucp = p;

    printf("sizeof unsigned integer is: %zu sizeof pointer to unsigned integer is: %zu\n", sizeof(*ip), sizeof(ip));
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(*ip); ++i)
    {
        printf("0x%x\n", ip[i]);
    }
    printf("now lets see what those hex numbers mean\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(*ip) * sizeof(*ip); ++i)
    {
        printf("0x%hhx = '%c'\n", ucp[i], ucp[i]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    test( argv[1] );
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/mSi58E

it should be enough for you to understand what is going on.

[image]

Comment: Note to new folks here on SO: when you read "undefined behavior" in C, it's wise to read that as "bug".